# MongoDB text search with multiple fields duplicate result set

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, text-search

I have a text index on my products collection. This index uses 3 columns with different weights as shown below. When I search for lets say "apple", I see that the same product is returned multiple times. It is not just for one product though, most of the products are duplicated. What may be the cause of this? Do I need to reindex my collection?
Thanks

```
{
    "v": 1,
    "key": {
        "_fts": "text",
        "_ftsx": 1
    },
    "name": "searchCollection",
    "ns": "local.product",
    "weights": {
        "categoryList": 3,
        "productInformation": 1,
        "title": 5
    },
    "default_language": "english",
    "language_override": "language",
    "textIndexVersion": 2
}
```

This is the result:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id": ObjectId("56b122913fa3dac80849fa54"),
    "title": "Apple - Apple TV - Black",
    "urlTitle": "apple---apple-tv---black",
    "price": 75.0,
    "imageList": ["https://test.s3.amazonaws.com/test.png"],
    "boxPrice": 1.0,
    "upcCode": "IBXBB4854433",
    "categoryList": "electronics,televisions & home theater,home theater accessories,apple home theater accessories,Apple,",
    "productInformation": "<div class=\"feature\">\r\n<h4>1080p capability</h4>\r\n<p>Watch high-resolution movies and TV shows from the iTunes Store; view videos and photos from the Internet and your Mac or PC in crisp 1080p.</p>\r\n</div></div>",
    "productSpecification": "&lt;p&gt;Get access to a world of instant entertainment with this product. Just connect to the Internet and stream movies, listen to music, and access a wide variety of other content.&lt;/p&gt;",
    "user": "1",
    "isPromoted": false,
    "createdAt": ISODate("2016-02-02T21:41:37.508Z"),
    "updatedAt": ISODate("2016-06-15T02:52:39.761Z"),
    "weight": "2",
    "productOptions": null,
    "hiddenPrice": "69.99",
    "viewCount": 8.0
}

/* 1 */
{
    "_id": "56b122913fa3dac80849fa54",
    "title": "Apple - Apple TV - Black",
    "urlTitle": "apple---apple-tv---black",
    "price": 75.0,
    "imageList": ["https://test.s3.amazonaws.com/test.png"],
    "boxPrice": 1.0,
    "upcCode": "IBXBB4854433",
    "categoryList": "electronics,televisions & home theater,home theater accessories,apple home theater accessories,Apple,",
    "productInformation": "<div class=\"feature\">\r\n<h4>1080p capability</h4>\r\n<p>Watch high-resolution movies and TV shows from the iTunes Store; view videos and photos from the Internet and your Mac or PC in crisp 1080p.</p>\r\n</div></div>",
    "productSpecification": "&lt;p&gt;Get access to a world of instant entertainment with this product. Just connect to the Internet and stream movies, listen to music, and access a wide variety of other content.&lt;/p&gt;",
    "user": "1",
    "isPromoted": false,
    "createdAt": ISODate("2016-02-02T21:41:37.508Z"),
    "updatedAt": ISODate("2016-03-30T14:33:42.731Z"),
    "weight": "2",
    "productOptions": null,
    "hiddenPrice": "69.99",
    "viewCount": 1.0,
    "score": 9.231043781725889
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id": ObjectId("57028d1d610bb00300e8b293"),
    "user": null,
    "title": "Apple Wired Mouse",
    "urlTitle": "apple-wired-mouse",
    "categoryList": "electronics,computers,computer accessories,apple computer accessories,Apple,",
    "boxPrice": 1.0,
    "imageList": ["https://test.s3.amazonaws.com/test.jpg"],
    "price": 47.0,
    "weight": "1",
    "productInformation": "<p style=\"color: rgb(0, 0, 0);background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\">It’s the wired mouse that reinvents the wheel — t</ul>",
    "productOptions": null,
    "hiddenPrice": "44",
    "isPromoted": false,
    "upcCode": "MB112LLB",
    "createdAt": ISODate("2016-04-04T15:49:49.760Z"),
    "updatedAt": ISODate("2016-06-14T13:15:11.174Z"),
    "viewCount": 1.0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id": "57028d1d610bb00300e8b293",
    "user": null,
    "title": "Apple Wired Mouse",
    "urlTitle": "apple-wired-mouse",
    "categoryList": "electronics,computers,computer accessories,apple computer accessories,Apple,",
    "boxPrice": 1.0,
    "imageList": ["https://test.s3.amazonaws.com/test.jpg"],
    "price": 47.0,
    "weight": "1",
    "productInformation": "<p style=\"color: rgb(0, 0, 0);background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\">It’s the wired mouse that reinvents the wheel</ul>",
    "productOptions": null,
    "hiddenPrice": "44",
    "isPromoted": false,
    "upcCode": "MB112LLB",
    "createdAt": ISODate("2016-04-04T15:49:49.760Z"),
    "updatedAt": ISODate("2016-04-07T13:22:09.108Z"),
    "score": 7.170701054107839
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id": ObjectId("57028390610bb00300e8b286"),
    "user": null,
    "title": "Nomad Silver Stand Apple Watch Charger",
    "urlTitle": "nomad-silver-stand-apple-watch-charger",
    "categoryList": "watches,womens smart watches,mens smart watches,computer accessories,apple womens smart watches,apple mens smart watches,apple computer accessories,nomad womens smart watches,nomad mens smart watches,nomad computer accessories,Apple,Nomad,",
    "boxPrice": 1.0,
    "imageList": ["https://test.s3.amazonaws.com/test.jpg"],
    "price": 39.0,
    "weight": "1",
    "productInformation": "<p style=\"color: rgb(0, 0, 0);background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\">Keep your Apple Watch safe and secure while </ul>",
    "productOptions": null,
    "hiddenPrice": "30",
    "isPromoted": false,
    "upcCode": "STAND-APPLE-S-001",
    "createdAt": ISODate("2016-04-04T15:09:04.884Z"),
    "updatedAt": ISODate("2016-06-14T12:43:10.327Z"),
    "viewCount": 1.0
}
```

Comment: can you share the output you get after searching for 'Apple'.. ?

Comment: @Nev It seems like there is a problem with _id vs ObjectId. Any suggestions?

Comment: based on the query result shared by you, how come the '_id' field has ObjectId in some and not in the others .. ? are you overwriting that field or your letting it auto-generate in all cases ? what is the query you have used for searching for 'Apple' ?

Comment: The problem was caused by using .native() from sailsjs. When I use this, the system doesn't return a model, instead returns an array. Since the objects in that array do not have their id fields specified as objects (objectId), the system considers them as new products, and inserts them into the product collection prior to inserting records into the related document (cart). Removing the product documents with string ids and adding an additional check for id field into the app fixed the problem.

Comment: That's great !! , you should post this as an actual answer to your question below instead of writing the solution in the comments, it will be useful for anyone else who comes across such a problem in the future.. !!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by using .native() from sailsjs. When I use this, the system doesn't return a model, instead returns an array. Since the objects in that array do not have their id fields specified as objects (objectId), the system considers them as new products, and inserts them into the product collection prior to inserting records into the related document (cart). Removing the product documents with string ids and adding an additional check for id field into the app fixed the problem.